# Time Stamps not working

Tags: c#

I am trying nce it turns the next day, but it doesn't. It just keeps on going. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you expect that? You never modify the `startTime` variable.

Comment: startTime will never be greater or equal to endTime, didn't you post this yesterday?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET he set it today at the very top.

Comment: @Bit, well yes, but it doesn't change in the loop, so once you get past the check once (and it always will given what he set it too, the condition will never change. Hence, he needs to set it again for that if statement to *ever* be entered.

Comment: Would it work if I add the statement "startTime = startTime.AddSeconds(i) right before events.Add(dataStart) ?

Comment: @WinstonJohns Is it so hard to just try it and find out?

Comment: Not the way you think it would... If you just want to make it stop executing tomorrow, forget the whole "startTime" check, just write `if (DateTime.Now >= endTime)` That variable will automatically update.

Comment: your condition should compare on `dataStart` not startTime >-endTime`

Comment: @DJKRAZE, Not a bad idea, but as written that variable would be out of scope for that if statement. I would use my method or that provided in the answer depending on what the OP is actually trying to do.

Comment: Oh boy, how many days have you already spent testing this? :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNet it would actually work if the OP would declare the variable outside the scope initially `TimeId`

Comment: @DJKRAZE, I know that, hence the *as written*. Either way it won't give the results the OP expects. That for loop will execute **way** faster than an iteration per second (unless he forgot a Thread.Sleep or something) so is not a good way of counting time no matter what.

Comment: I totally agree.. I actually think that he should declare and or set the variable something like this to get at the actual timestamp or TimeSpan code such as Felipe has displayed `var timestamp = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss.fff}", DateTime.Now);`

Answer (score 2):

I understad you want to limit the time execution of your method. You need to use the `TimeSpan` to check if the loop pass the limite of time from `Now`, for sample if you do not want to pass `1` hour you could do something like this:

```
// start Time
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
// time limit to execute
TimeSpan timeLimit = new TimeSpan(0 /*days*/, 1/*hours*/, 0 /*minute*/, 0/*second*/)

for (int i = 0; i < 87400; i++) 
{
    // get the time used to execute 
    var executionTime = DateTime.Now - startTime;

    // check if it has exceeded
    if (executionTime >= timeLimit)
        break;

    // rest of method
}
```

Comment: +1 This works if you want it to execute for exactly one hour. Its hard to tell if thats what the OP wants, or if he wants it to stop as soon as the calendar day turns. Good method though!

Comment: Yes, it's for *one hour*, but the question is not easy to understand! :)